# How to correctly mount/bind/... a local (host) dir into a docker container

Tags: windows, mount, docker, windows-11, docker-for-windows

I'm currently using Windows 11 and I try to construct a docker file for my development environment, which can be seen below. For me, the line `RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/$username/src` is interesting. I understand "*build context*" as the folder in which the **Dockerfile** lies. [From the docs:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mount)

> `RUN --mount` allows you to create mounts that process running as part of the build can access. This can be used to bind files from other part of the build without copying [...] or creating cache locations to speed up your build.
>
> `RUN --mount=type=bind` [...] allows binding directories (read-only) in the context or in an image to the build container.

So at best I would like to have something like a bind mount via [a command like this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/): `docker run -dit --mount type=bind,source="${PWD}\target",target=/home/foo/src` (from PowerShell) or `docker run -dit --mount type=bind,source="%cd%\target",target=/home/foo/src` (from cmd) ... for some reason `$username` didn't work in `,target=/home/foo/src` - but I somehow need to get this inside the **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.6.6
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.2.1

ARG username=foo
ENV RVM_DIR "/home/$username/.rvm"
ENV NVM_DIR "/home/$username/.nvm"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
#libssl1.0-dev:
#  Installed: (none)
#  Candidate: (none)
#  Version table:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl build-essential whois unzip sudo libpq-dev passwd git wget


RUN echo "$username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/$username
## create user for Heizkosten-Plattform
RUN adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash $username
## continue as non-root user
USER $username


## create application directory (as non-root user)
RUN sudo mkdir /opt/$username && sudo chown $username:$username /opt/$username

# 0. Git
WORKDIR /opt/$username

RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// 
RUN git init 
RUN git config --global user.name "John Doe"
RUN git config --global user.email "johndoe@example.com" 

# 1. Preparations for RVM
RUN sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
RUN sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
RUN sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev -y
RUN sudo apt-get install libpq-dev -y

# 2.a RVM (Ruby Version Manager)
RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
RUN \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
# \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
RUN . $RVM_DIR/scripts/rvm # Doen't seem to do much. source instead of . doesn't work.
RUN $RVM_DIR/bin/rvm install $RUBY_VERSION
RUN $RVM_DIR/bin/rvm use default $RUBY_VERSION

# 3 NVM (Node Version Manager)
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use $NODE_VERSION
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
RUN npm install 

# 2.b # Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
ENV PATH $PATH:$RVM_DIR/rubies/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$RVM_DIR/bin

#MOUNT
RUN mkdir ~/src
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/$username/src 
# ,from     Build stage or image name for the root of the source. Defaults to the build context.

WORKDIR /home/$username/src
run pwd && ls -la /home/foo/src && exit 1
RUN bundle install

# make port of rails server available
EXPOSE 3000
```

---

`run pwd && ls -la /home/foo/src && exit 1` is just to verify that the `src` dir is still empty:

```
------
 > [28/29] RUN pwd && ls -la /home/foo/src && exit 1:
#32 0.449 /home/foo/src
#32 0.451 total 8
#32 0.451 drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Oct 17 13:04 .
#32 0.451 drwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo 4096 Oct 17 13:04 ..
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pwd && ls -la /home/foo/src && exit 1]: exit code: 1
```

(I use `&& exit 1` to jump out and let docker keep the output)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) - `RUN` command is designed to execute things when image is being built. You have given it a bind mount definition, but no program or command to execute. What you'd normally do is mount the data and act upon it within that same `RUN` instruction. Like so:

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/$username/src bundle install
```

or to see what you have mounted

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/$username/src ls -la /home/foo/src
```

I haven't seen this explicitly stated in the documentation, but from what I understand it is implied that Dockerfile mounts are only active for the duration of the respective `RUN` instruction. You can see this illustrated in the [official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/mounts/). Note how every `RUN` instruction has it's own mount definition, even when they are identical. Also worth noting that Dockerfile *bind* mounts are by default *read-only*, therefore attempted modification of the mounted tree will normally raise an error.

I would also suggest you use the `WORKDIR` instruction in place of `RUN mkdir`. It [does exactly what you need](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) by creating all of the necessary directories along the path specified and changes into the final one, which ties nicely into the following `RUN` instruction. Such that you can create a mount target, mount into it and act upon mounted data right away. E.g.:

```
WORKDIR /home/$username/src
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/$username/src bundle install
```

As you rightfully pointed out bind mounting at container run time is an alternative approach. As run time binds remain available until container is stopped.